# Booting from an SSD clone of a hard disk on Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, hard-drive, ssd, clone

I want to replace my hard drive on a Ubuntu NUC system. Its the only drive and its connected by a USB sata adapter.

I did this once already by just cloning to another hard drive, and the replacement boots fine. This adapter has just the one slot.

The I cloned it again to a sata sdd. I plugged into the same usb sata adapter and the NUC boot manager doesn't like it. This is a GUID partitioned disk, with an EFI partition.

When I look at the cloned SSD on a running system, all the partitions fsck  ok.

The cloning is with a dual slot sata box that does stand alone disk duplication.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was the one slot usb sata adapter that couldn function properly with sata hard drives, but not the SSD which had the same size and contents. It works properly including acting as a boot device in the two slot (using just one).

So I'm good.

Comment: +1; But your answer would be even more useful for other people, if you describe with more details which hardware, tool(s) and steps how you cloned to the SSD. Please check also if the drives were exactly the same size (on the single byte level), or slightly different, even when the nominal size is the same.